# Get month and year from datetime SQL server compact 3.5 in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone-7, datepicker, sql-server-ce

I have a datepicker toolkit to be used to get the date. after the date was selected, I want to get just the month and year of that datepicker. After doing so, I am trying to query from my database to see if the month and year is selected or exist and will output it in my budgetAmount.Text. I am not sure how to get the month and year. How could I do so. Below is my code:

```
DateTime d = expenseDate.Value.Value;

IList<Budgets> budg = null;
IQueryable<Budgets> bud = from Date in c.Budgets where Date = d select Date;
budg = bud.ToList();

budgetAmount.Text = budg.ToString();
```

The code above will only get the full date which includes the day. I want to just get the month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime dt = expenseDate.SelectedDate.Date;
DateTime d = dt.AddDays(-dt.Day+1);
```